# Component.js file not created for new component angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding a new user component and also import in app.module file but when run server user.component js file not created

**folder structure**

```
typescript
  components
     user
       user.component.ts
  app.component.ts
  app.module.ts
  main.ts
```

**app.module.js**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { UserComponent }   from './components/user/user.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ 
                    AppComponent, 
                    UserComponent 
                ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-listing',
    template: '<h4>Users here</h4>'
})

export class UserComponent {

}
```